# modificar datos en shape para hacer mapas

Tags: base-de-datos, r, rstudio

¿Qué tal? Estoy tratando de armar un mapa con Rstudio con los paquetes tidy y sf. Pero una de mis bases de datos tiene nombres de columnas o filas que están mal y necesito modificar el shape. ¿Alguien sabe decirme como hago para realizar las modificaciones? Gracias

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: Bienvenida a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y de paso ganes tu primer medalla, también es muy importante que leas [ask] para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que sea bien recibida por la comunidad mejorando así, tus chances de obtener buenas respuestas.

Comment: Tengo tres capas para armar un mapa, un shape del mapa de Argentina, otro de las Provincias de Argentina y el tercero de las Reservas de Biosfera, el de las Reservas tiene nombres de columnas y filas que tengo que corregir, o sino no puedo continuar el trabajo. No sé cómo hacer la modificación. si me podrían ayudar.

Comment: Para modificar nombres de columnas puedes hacer algo así `colnames(df) <- vector_con nuevos_nombres`

Comment: tengo que llamar primero a la base con la que estoy trabajando? Gracias!

Comment: Pude modificar el nombre de la columna, a partir de su recomendación. Ahora preciso cambiar nombres dentro de cada columna. Ejemplo, en la columna RB: tengo que modificar valores internos

Comment: Hola @Aria. Bienvenido a [es.so]. Podría dar un poco más de información a quien quiera ayudarte (ayudanos a ayudarte). Te recomiendo [edit] la pregunta agregando una muestra de los shapes que necesitas modificar, así como de el objetivo que buascas. Y sería bueno que realices el [tour] y leer [ask]. La idea es ofrecer un [mcve] en todas las preguntas.